# Extracting rows that factor levels in two columns do not match in columns of another dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

I have a simple, correct concordance table (dataframe in R) of states and state codes:

```
statecodeconcordance<-structure(list(State.Code = structure(1:5, .Label =
c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), class = "factor"), State.Name = structure(1:5, 
.Label = c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California"), class 
= "factor")), .Names = c("State.Code", "State.Name"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

which looks like this:

```
   State.Code State.Name
1           1    Alabama
2           2     Alaska
3           3    Arizona
4           4   Arkansas
5           5 California
```

and then I have a dataframe with errors in it, in which some states are assigned the wrong state code (plus various unrelated columns):

```
sampledata<-structure(list(State.Code = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L,
 4L, 3L, 1L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "5"), class = "factor"), 
State.Name = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L), .Label = 
c("Alabama", "Alaska", "Arizona", "California"), class = "factor"), 
Unrelated.Data = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L), 
.Label = c("some_data", "more_data", "other_data", "data_squared", 
"alternate_data", "yet_more_data", "so_much_data", 
"running_out_of_modifiers_for_data", "still_more_data", "last_data"), class 
= "factor")), .Names = c("State.Code", "State.Name", "Unrelated.Data"), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

which looks like this:

```
   State.Code State.Name                    Unrelated.Data
1           1    Alabama                         some_data
2           2    Alabama                         more_data
3           1    Alabama                        other_data
4           1    Alabama                      data_squared
5           1    Alabama                    alternate_data
6           2     Alaska                     yet_more_data
7           5    Arizona                      so_much_data
8           3    Arizona running_out_of_modifiers_for_data
9           1 California                   still_more_data
10          5 California                         last_data
```

How can I subset the latter dataframe to return only those rows in which the state-code pairs do not match the pairs in the concordance table (i.e., those rows with `Alabama` in `State.Name` but a non-`1` number in `State.Code`, `Alaska` in `State.Name` but a non-`2` number in `State.Code`, etc.)?

Ideal output:

```
   State.Code State.Name                    Unrelated.Data
2           2    Alabama                         more_data
7           5    Arizona                      so_much_data
9           1 California                   still_more_data
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dplyr` package:

```
library(dplyr)
anti_join(sampledata, statecodeconcordance, by = c("State.Code","State.Name"))

#   State.Code State.Name  Unrelated.Data 
# 1          5    Arizona    so_much_data 
# 2          2    Alabama       more_data 
# 3          1 California still_more_data
```

Answer (score 2):

We can use the `data.table` package.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(sampledata)
setDT(statecodeconcordance)

sampledata[!statecodeconcordance, on = c("State.Code", "State.Name")]
   State.Code State.Name  Unrelated.Data
1:          2    Alabama       more_data
2:          5    Arizona    so_much_data
3:          1 California still_more_data
```